# How to do this integral: $\int_0^\infty e^{ikt}\sin(pt)dt$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I need to do this:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{ikt}\sin(pt)dt$$

I already have the solution, I'm just clueless on how to actually calculate it. I've tried several changes,integration by parts and extending it to a $(-\infty,\infty)$ integral so it'd be a simple Fourier transform, but I can't solve it.

I would appreciate solution or hints. Thank you very much.

EDIT:
The result must be of the form:
$$\frac{a}{s}\pm ibs\text{ sign}(k)\delta(-p^2)$$
where $a,b$ are constants, and $s$ is the module of a vector measured with a metric of minkowsky type $\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$, where the $0$ component is $k$ and the $3d$ part has module $p$.

All in all, the integral comes from calculating a green function that ends up being:

$$\frac{1}{4\pi(x-x')}\int_0^\infty e^{-ik(t-t')}\sin[k(x-x')]dk$$
And the result should be:
$$\frac{1}{8\pi^2(x-x')^2}-\frac{i}{8\pi}\text{ sign}(t-t')\delta(-(x-x')^2)$$

The constants in each term $\textit{may}$ be wrong, but that's the structure of the result.

Comment: That integral doesn't exist as a Lebesgue integral or an improper Riemann integral. In what sense should the integral be interpreted?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not sure whether this will be useful to you (I've never studied complex analysis), but Mathematica reports the answer to be: $$\frac{p}{p^2-k^2},\qquad |\Im(p)| < \Im(k)$$

Comment: Ah, if we have $\Im k > 0$, then it does exist (for $\lvert \Im p\rvert < \Im k$). I assumed $k$ and $p$ real.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry for the lack of information. $k$ and $p$ are real, I've seen this integral in physics (in quantum field theory). What they do if shift $k$ into the complex plane by adding $\epsilon i$ to it so it can be done. I need to know how it can be done in that case. So we can consider that $\Im k>0$. Btw the solution I have is something of the form $a+b$, where $b$ has a $\delta$ function.

Comment: And then they let $\epsilon \to 0$ and you get the distribution $$\varphi \mapsto \operatorname{v.p.} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{p}{p^2-k^2}\varphi(k)\,dk$$ as the Fourier transform, right?

Comment: As Daniel said.  This diverges when $p$ and $k$ are real, $p \ne 0$.  Do you want complex numbers for $p$ and $k$?  Perhaps you should say so, then.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm rather intrigued, as the integral is undefined for real $k$ (as illustrated by GEdgar), so how does this technique work and what does it "mean"? Also, I've never seen a $\mathrm{v.p.}$ before an integral before - What does that mean?

Comment: @Shaktal $\operatorname{v.p.}$ is short for "valeur principale", it's a principal value integral, one omits short symmetric intervals around the poles, and takes the limit as the length of the intervals shrinks to $0$. If you replace $k$ with $k+i\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ in the integrand, you get a nice standard integral, that gives you $$\psi_\varepsilon \colon k \mapsto \int_0^\infty e^{i(k+i\varepsilon)t}\sin (pt)\,dt = \frac{p}{p^2 - (k+i\varepsilon)^2}.$$ Now if you take $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \psi_\varepsilon$ in the sense of of distributions, you get the above.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahh right; thanks for explaining that, I'm familiar with $\mathrm{p.v.}$ for the principle value of functions, but I'd never seen $\mathrm{v.p.}$ before! I understand what you mean now, thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer That I understand. I don't understand though how can a delta function appear from that expression.

Comment: Not sure where you see a Dirac measure (delta function) appear. Is this supposed to yield a Dirac measure in some way?

Comment: @DanielFischer I edited the question with info about the original integral and result.

Answer (score 3):

Under the condition that all integrals exist ($|\operatorname{Im}(p)|<\operatorname{Im}(k)$)
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{ikt}\sin(pt)\,dt&=\frac{1}{2\,i}\int_0^\infty e^{ikt}(e^{ipt}-e^{-ipt})\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\,i}\Bigl(\frac{e^{i(k+p)t}}{i(k+p)}-\frac{e^{i(k-p)t}}{i(k-p)}\Bigr|_0^\infty\Bigl)\\
&=\frac12\Bigl(\frac{1}{k+p}-\frac{1}{k-p}\Bigr).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's illustrate the non-existence.

I took $k=2,p=1$.
The graph illustrates
$$
\mathrm{Re}\int_0^x e^{i2t}\sin(t)\;dt 
$$
for $x$ from 0 to 20.  It continues with period $2\pi$.

[image: graph]